# jQuery slideToggle() doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

Hello my first time here,

I got a basic jQuery slideToggle and it doens't work.
any solutions?

Thanks for reading this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ucp").click(function(){
                $("#test").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="http://www.kevinheisen.nl" target="_blank"><img src="style/lacp.png" alt="acp logo"></a>
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Afmelden</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.kevinheisen.nl">Vraag hulp</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">preview website</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ACP startpagina</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ucp">Gebruikers beheer</div>
        <div id="test">hallo hallo hallo hallo</div>
        <div class="project">Projecten<br /><span id="menu">Klik hier om groter te maken</span></div>
        <div class="updates">Updates<br /><span id="menu">Klik hier om groter te maken</span></div>
        <div class="homecontent">Home content<br /><span id="menu">Klik hier om groter te maken</span></div>
        <div class="portofolio">portfolio<br /><span id="menu">Klik hier om groter te maken</span></div>
        <div class="about">Over mij<br /><span id="menu">Klik hier om groter te maken</span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

okay this all of my code. I know i can decrease the css.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Acptitle';
    src:url('/admin/style/CGFLocustResistance.ttf'), 
    url('/admin/style/CGFLocustResistance.eot'); /* IE9 */
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Acpdefault';
    src:url('/admin/style/ccaps.ttf'),
    url('/admin/style/ccaps.eot'); /* IE9 */
}

body {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #585858;
    background-image: url('/style/lacp.png');
}

#menu {
    font-size: 8px;
}

.header {
    height: 180px;
    min-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3A3A3A;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.header > .nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.header > .nav > ul > li {
    font-family: 'Acptitle';
    text-align: center;
}

.header > .nav > ul > li > a:link, a:visited{
    font-size: 12px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000; 
    margin: 0 10px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    background: #3A3A3A;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 15px;
    color: black;
}

.header > .nav > ul > li > a:hover, a:active {
    color: #000000;
    background: #212121;
}

#ucp, #test{
    font-family: 'Acptitle';
    margin: 15px 0 0 5%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#test{
    display: none;
    height: 300px;
    width: 40%;
}

.project {
    font-family: 'Acptitle';
    margin: 15px 5% 0 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 45px;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.updates {
    font-family: 'Acptitle';
    margin: 15px 5% 0 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 45px;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.homecontent {
    font-family: 'Acptitle';
    margin: 15px 0 0 5%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.portofolio {
    font-family: 'Acptitle';
    margin: 15px 0 0 5%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.about {
    font-family: 'Acptitle';
    margin: 15px 5% 0 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 45px;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This everything. I have no problems on other site. i think my websitebrowser isn't the problem. i'm using Google chrome btw. i tried also in IE9 and firefox.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: You need to check to see whether there are errors in the console. Try removing all of the JS references except for jQuery.

Comment: does #test has a width and height? sometimes it messes up without dimensions

Comment: Nope, with height and width it still doens't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to hide the element that you want to toggle first.

So in your case you need to hide the `test` div.

**CSS:**

```
#test {
    display:none;
}
```

It should now work.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PChQm/)

**EDIT:** On closer inspection, you shouldn't have to hide it. Check that the jquery library is referenced correctly as Jai has pointed out below.

Comment: i didn't post my css. But i've hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens if you give a library src without any protocol like in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/lib..."></script>
//                                 ^-------Here
```

try once with by putting some protocol like `https:` or `http:`

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have no reputation to vote. i started here today. i have stil my problem. but thanks for comment. :P

Comment: Downvoting doesn't earn you the repos, better questions asked will earn you for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no JavaScript errors, your code should work just fine. Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wG4fP/) that demonstrates it working. When you click on `Gebruikers beheer` the `hallo hallo hallo hallo` toggles in and out of view using a slide effect.

However, it's possible that the other scripts which you're referencing could be causing JavaScript errors, which would cause *everything* to break. One troubleshooting technique is to reduce the code so that you're only using that which is absolutely essential. Try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#ucp").click(function () {
          $("#test").slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="ucp">Gebruikers beheer</div>
  <div id="test">hallo hallo hallo hallo</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's a php file does it make sense?

Comment: I don't see any PHP in your code, but a PHP file with nothing but HTML should still work just fine...

Comment: I make the design before writing php.

Comment: That's okay. Create a blank test page and try the code that I've posted. It should work.

Comment: Can you post all of your code? Just copy and paste everything in the file. There must be something else going on...Also, are you sure that the issue isn't with the browser? Do you have JavaScript enabled? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I got it working now...

I replaced `<script type="text/javascript" scr="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` 
for 
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` i tried the same link before but it didn't work. but now it does. anyway thanks for the help guys. EDIT: BTW, any idea how to close this post of something?

Comment: I don't think you can close the post now that it has answers, but you could always mark my answer as correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its working in fiddle...try here http://jsfiddle.net/CdWnx/

Could it be that you missed http part in jQuery reference?

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```